# requires clause on non-template friend function of a template class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, friend-function, requires-clause

Reproducible code as below or on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8aW5TxcYe) compiles with clang trunk and MSVC but fails with gcc trunk. Given that non-template friend function of a template class could be constrained by requires clause, is it a gcc bug here?

```
template< typename Derived >
struct base {
    friend void foo(Derived const& d) requires requires { bar(d); } {
        bar(d);
    }
};

namespace adl {
    struct S: base<S> {
        friend void bar(S const&) {}
    };
}
using adl::S;

void test(S const& s) {
    foo(s); // gcc error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
}
```

Comment: friend declaration was only found by ADL-like. Not sure `foo(const Derived&)` can be found (`foo(const base<Derived>&)` should though).

Comment: It may be a regression. It works in gcc 12.2 and before.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it should. Base class is included in the set of lookup.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I think it's a bug so I filed a bugreport: [Bug 108303](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108303)